# Silverlight Datagrid Refresh

Tags: silverlight, wcf, data-binding, datagrid

So I have a datagrid in Silverlight that is bound to a WCF that populates a list of class. I basically a pass a parameter to a Linq query. When I do a second query I get double the results, a third triple and so forth. What can I do to make it so when I send a call out to the service that I only get one set of results.  I have attached my code in case it helps anyone.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        dgOrder.ItemsSource = null;
        Uri address = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../Services/Service1.svc");
        //var client = new Services.dataserviceClient("CustomBinding_dataservice", address.AbsoluteUri);
        var client = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client("CustomBinding_Service1", address.AbsolutePath);

        client.GetOrderCompleted += (s, ea) =>
            {
                dgOrder.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                //dgOrder.ColumnWidth.Value = 100;





                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("SKU", "SKU"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("productname", "Product Name"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("itemnumber", "Item Number"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("cost", "Cost"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("asin", "ASIN"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("pendingorder", "Rank"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("rank", "Node"));
                //dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("w4", "AMZN"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("amazon", "AMZN"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("ourprice", "OurPrice"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("bbprice", "BuyBox"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("afner", "AFN"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("quantity", "INV"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("w4", "W4"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("w3", "W3"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("w2", "W2"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("w1", "W1"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("order", "Order"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("total", "Total"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("profit", "Profit"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("percent", "Percent"));
                dgOrder.Columns.Add(CreateHyperlink("asin"));
                dgOrder.ItemsSource = ea.Result;
                Original = ea.Result;

            };
        client.GetOrderAsync(txtCompany.Text);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is , you are creating a new(duplicate) event handler every time you press the Button. Due to having an extra event for each button pres you do, you get extra sets of data. You need to create your Event.Completed method outside the Button.Cliked event.

To clarify:

```
    public partial class NewPage : Page
    {
        Uri address = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../Services/Service1.svc");
        ServiceReference2.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client("CustomBinding_Service1", address.AbsolutePath);

        public NewPage()
        {
            client.GetOrderCompleted += (s, ea) =>
            {
                //YOUR CODE
            };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            dgOrder.ItemsSource = null;
            client.GetOrderAsync(txtCompany.Text);

        }

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what I do with event?

Comment: the only problem that var can't be used as a class member.

Comment: so change var to ServiceReference2.Service1Client